# How to compare two text field values using ext js

Tags: extjs

I have small query,i have two text fields.here my query is if i enter a value in second text field,If the value is greater than first text field it's show pop up message box,
how can i implement this requirement.Any one can u please help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

working fiddle here : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/osl

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Check Fields',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'Number1',
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        id: 'num1'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'text2',
        fieldLabel: 'Number2',
        xtype: 'numberfield', 
        listeners:{
            change: function( me, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ){
                if (Ext.getCmp("num1").getValue() > newValue){
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Field 1 greater than Field2');
                }
            }
        }
    }],
```

});

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement that. One possible way would be:

```js
Ext.widget({
    xtype: 'container',
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'textfield'
    },
    items: [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Field 1',
            name: 'f1'
        },
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Field 2',
            listeners: {
                'change': function() {
                    if (this.getValue() > this.ownerCt.down('textfield[name="f1"]').getValue()) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Attention', 'The value of the second field is greater than the value of the first one');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Hi Drakes, Thanks for responding to my post,but here i am getting one issue if i enter each digit it's showing pop up,but i want if the value is greater than the first textfield value that's time i need to show the pop up can u please share any idea to me.

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting that. The popup is already *only* showing when the second textfield value is greater, isn't it? Are you seeing the popup when the values are the same or what?

Answer (score -2):

(I'm using jquery for example)

first text field id=A
second text field id=B

```
var a=$('#A');
 var b=$('#B');

$("#B").on(function() {
   if(a>b){
 alert("B number is greater than A number");
  }
});
```